# How make random order in each group of rows in one sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-order-by

I have table 'stock' (MariaDB database), which contains list of products. Each product have id, title, price and amount.
Some products have amount > 0 and price=0, which means that price is undefined. Some products have defined price (price>0), but amount=0. And third group have price>0 and amount>0.

I want to select products from this table in such order

1. products with price>0 and amount>0
2. products with price>0 and amount=0
3. products with price=0 and amount>0

**And each of these 3 groups must have random order of rows**. Not random order for all rows in query, but random order in each group, **preserving the sequence of groups** - 1, 2, 3

How should the sql query look like for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conditional sort:

```
select *
from stock
order by 
    case 
        when price > 0 and amount > 0 then 1
        when price > 0 and amount = 0 then 2
        when price = 0 and amount > 0 then 3
        else 4
    end,
    rand()
```

Comment: What about records not matched to those 3 conditions? May be add `else 4` section to case condition?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev: then the `case` expression returns `null`, which is sorted last, since we use ascending order. So need for an `else` branch. Side note: your answer does not work: first, you would need parentheses around each member, and even so, there is no guarantee about the ordering of rows in the final result. [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html): *Use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows*

Comment: You right about my answer, I just deleted it. Also I tested sorting with NULL values: both MySQL & MariaDB place NULLs first in ASC ordering, PostgreSQL set NULLs at end of list. https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=7449fe45bebb4b46f59cb2f5f120b390&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev: ah yes, you are right (I think Postgres follows ANSI standard, but apparently not MySQL). Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort them like this:

```
order by 
  price > 0 and amount > 0 desc,
  price > 0 and amount = 0 desc,
  price = 0 and amount > 0 desc,
  rand()
```

because each of the boolean expressions in the `order by` clause evaluates to 1 or 0 for `true` or `false`.

Or with some math involved:

```
order by 
  10 * (price > 0) + (amount > 0) desc,
  rand()
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL/MariaDB you can simplify your logic to:

```
order by (price > 0) desc, (amount > 0) desc
```

In these databases, boolean expressions are ordered with "false" first and then "true" (because false --> 0 and true --> 1).  Hence, the `desc` does exactly what you want:  the valid prices first and then the valid amounts.